# Adding a badge in a jQuery attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

From the example below, how could I insert a badge or some formatted text (e.g. colored bold font) at the end of the text that appears when hovering the circle?

```js
$(".tooltip-elem").hover(function() {
  var tooltipText = $(this).data("tooltip");
  //console.log(tooltipText);
  $("#placeholder").html(tooltipText);
});
$(".tooltip-elem").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("#placeholder").html("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg style="display: inline-block;" width="250" height="150">
      <circle class="tooltip-elem" id="circle_1" cx="30" cy="45" r="25" data-tooltip="That's a circle !" />
      
</svg>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'badge' could you show an example of your desired output

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Boostrap tooltip to show up correctly, you must use the appropriate attributes. There is no `data-tooltip` attribute. The HTML should go in the `title` attribute and the `toggle`, `html`, and `placement` data attributes should be defined.

See the docs: ***[Boostrap 4.0 Docs - Tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/)***

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```css
:root {
  --tooltip-background: #A00;
}

.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background: var(--tooltip-background);
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=right] .arrow::before,
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-right .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: var(--tooltip-background);
}

.badge {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.badge::after {
  content: '\1F600';
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<svg style="display: inline-block;" width="250" height="150">
  <circle id="circle_1" class="red-tooltip"
    cx="30" cy="45" r="25"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-html="true"
    data-placement="right"
    title="<h4>That's a circle ! <span class='badge'>my badge</span></h4>"/>  
</svg>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I am not trying to re-position the text. What I meant was trying to insert a badge inside the "That's a cricle !" text like so: `...data-tooltip="<h4>That's a circle ! <span class="badge">my badge</span></h4>"`

Comment: @6PO0222 Boostrap does not have a `data-tooltip` attribute. It utilizes the `title` attribute's text.

Comment: You are right "attribute" is not the proper term. Using a tooltip will place the text next to the element hovered. I wanted to place the text at a fixed position in the page (for multiple elements potentially).

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way.

```js
$(".tooltip-elem").hover(function() {
  var tooltipText = $(this).data("tooltip");
  $("#placeholder").html(tooltipText);
}, function() {
  $("#placeholder").html("");
});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<svg style="display: inline-block;" width="250" height="150">
      <circle class="tooltip-elem" id="circle_1" cx="30" cy="45" r="25" data-tooltip="That's a circle ! <span class='label label-primary'>my badge</span>" />
      
</svg>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: Good one but why are you including jquery twice? Also if you look in hover [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover) it accepts an optional 2nd function that gets run on mouse leave so using that you make your code more compact no need of a separate `$(".tooltip-elem").on("mouseleave"`

Comment: @Viney Sorry, I removed one jQuery call. I am not sure why but if I do not explicity mention `mouseleave`, the text remains displayed.